# ForeignKeyConstraint requires the child key values (0) to exist in the parent table

Tags: c#, mysql

I can`t INSERT ROW master - details.

```
    private string strSelectComprobante()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  SELECT ";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.NroCpte,";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.TipoCpte,";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Fecha,";      //0
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Cliente,";    //1
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Usuario,";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Descripcion";
        strSQL += " FROM";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante";
        strSQL += " WHERE";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.TipoCpte = 'S'";
        if (!blnTodos)
        {
            strSQL += "     AND TbComprobante.NroCpte = 0 ";
        }

        return strSQL;
    }

    private string strUpdateComprobante()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  UPDATE TbComprobante SET ";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Fecha = ?Fecha,";      //0
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Cliente = ?Cliente,";    //1
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Usuario = ?Usuario,";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.Descripcion = ?Descripcion";
        strSQL += " WHERE";
        strSQL += "     TbComprobante.NroCpte = ?NroCpte";
        strSQL += "     AND TbComprobante.TipoCpte = 'S'";

        return strSQL;
    }

    private string strInsertComprobante()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  INSERT INTO TbComprobante ( ";
        strSQL += "     NroCpte,";        //0
        strSQL += "     TipoCpte,";
        strSQL += "     Fecha,";       //2
        strSQL += "     Cliente,";       //3
        strSQL += "     Usuario,";
        strSQL += "     Descripcion)";
        strSQL += " VALUES(";
        strSQL += "     ?NroCpte,";        //0
        strSQL += "     ?TipoCpte,";
        strSQL += "     ?Fecha,";       //2
        strSQL += "     ?Cliente,";       //3
        strSQL += "     ?Usuario,";
        strSQL += "     ?Descripcion)";
        return strSQL;
    }

    private string strSelectDetalle()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  SELECT ";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.NroCpte,";        //0
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.NroDetalle,";        //1
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.TipoCpte,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Producto,";       //2
        strSQL += "     TbProducto.Denominacion,";
        strSQL += "     TbProducto.Unidad,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.CostoUnt,";       //5
        strSQL += "     TbProducto.PrecioUnt,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Cantidad,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Descuento,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Monto";
        strSQL += " FROM";
        strSQL += "         TbDetalle";
        strSQL += "     INNER JOIN TbProducto ON";
        strSQL += "         TbDetalle.Producto = TbProducto.Producto";
        strSQL += " WHERE";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.TipoCpte = 'S'";
        if (!blnTodos)
        {
            strSQL += "     AND TbDetalle.NroCpte = 0 ";
        }              
        strSQL += " ORDER BY";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Producto";
        return strSQL;
    }

    private string strUpdateDetalle()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  UPDATE TbDetalle SET ";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.TipoCpte = 'S',";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.CostoUnt = ?CostoUnt,";       //3
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.PrecioUnt = ?PrecioUnt,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Cantidad = ?Cantidad,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Descuento = ?Descuento,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Monto = ?Monto";
        strSQL += " WHERE";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.NroCpte = ?NroCpte";
        strSQL += "     AND TbDetalle.TipoCpte = 'S'";
        strSQL += "     AND TbDetalle.NroDetalle = ?NroDetalle";

        return strSQL;
    }

    private string strDeleteDetalle()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  DELETE FROM TbDetalle ";
        strSQL += " WHERE";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.NroCpte = ?NroCpte";
        strSQL += "     AND TbDetalle.TipoCpte = 'S'";
        strSQL += "     AND TbDetalle.NroDetalle = ?NroDetalle";

        return strSQL;
    }


    private string strInsertDetalle()
    {
        string strSQL;
        strSQL = "  INSERT INTO TbDetalle ( ";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.NroCpte,";        //0
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.NroDetalle,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.TipoCpte,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Producto,";       //2
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.CostoUnt,";       //5
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.PrecioUnt,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Cantidad,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Descuento,";
        strSQL += "     TbDetalle.Monto)";
        strSQL += " VALUES(";
        strSQL += "     ?NroCpte,";
        strSQL += "     ?NroDetalle,";
        strSQL += "     'S',";
        strSQL += "     ?Producto,";
        strSQL += "     ?CostoUnt,";
        strSQL += "     ?PrecioUnt,";
        strSQL += "     ?Cantidad,";
        strSQL += "     ?Descuento,";
        strSQL += "     ?Monto)";
        return strSQL;
    }

    private int GrabarNroCpte(long intNroCpte)
    {
        string strSQL;
        MySqlCommand MyCmd;
        int intRowsAfects = 0;

        strSQL = "  UPDATE TbNroCpte";
        strSQL += "     SET NroCpte = " + intNroCpte;
        strSQL += " WHERE TipoCpte = 'S'";

        try
        {
            MyCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            MyCmd.Connection = Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx;
            MyCmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            intRowsAfects  = MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return intRowsAfects;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "GrabarNroCpte", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return intRowsAfects;
        }
    }

    private int GrabarComprobante(long intNroCpte)
    {
        int intRowsAfects = 0;
        try
        {
            //Actualiza comprobante
            CMDComprobante = new MySqlCommand(strUpdateComprobante(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Fecha", MySqlDbType.Datetime);
            CMDComprobante.Parameters["?Fecha"].Value = DtFecha.Value;
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Cliente", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Cliente");
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Usuario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 5, "Usuario");
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Descripcion", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "Descripcion");
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?NroCpte", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "NroCpte").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
            SDAComprobante.UpdateCommand = CMDComprobante;

            //Inserta comprobante
            CMDComprobante = new MySqlCommand(strInsertComprobante(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Fecha", MySqlDbType.Datetime);
            CMDComprobante.Parameters["?Fecha"].Value = DtFecha.Value;
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Cliente", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Cliente");
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Usuario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 5, "Usuario");
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?Descripcion", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "Descripcion");
            CMDComprobante.Parameters.Add("?NroCpte", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4);
            CMDComprobante.Parameters["?NroCpte"].Value = intNroCpte;
            SDAComprobante.InsertCommand = CMDComprobante;

            DataTable UpdateComprobante;
            UpdateComprobante = dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
            if (UpdateComprobante != null)
            {
                intRowsAfects = SDAComprobante.Update(UpdateComprobante);
                dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].AcceptChanges();
            }

            DataTable InsertComprobante;
            InsertComprobante = dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
            if (InsertComprobante != null)
            {
                intRowsAfects = SDAComprobante.Update(InsertComprobante);
                dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].AcceptChanges();
            }

            return intRowsAfects;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "GrabarComprobante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return intRowsAfects;
        }
    }

    private int GrabarDetalle(long intNroCpte)
    {
        int intRowsAfects = 0;
        try
        {
            //Actualiza Detalle
            CMDDetalle = new MySqlCommand(strUpdateDetalle(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?NroDetalle", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "NroDetalle");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Producto", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Producto");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?CostoUnt", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 7, "CostoUnt");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?PrecioUnt", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 2, "PrecioUnt");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Cantidad", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "Cantidad");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Descuento", MySqlDbType.Int32, 3, "Descuento");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Monto", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 2, "Monto");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?NroCpte", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "NroCpte");
            SDADetalle.UpdateCommand = CMDDetalle;

            //Eliminar fila de Detalle
            CMDDetalle = new MySqlCommand(strDeleteDetalle(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?NroCpte", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "NroCpte");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?NroDetalle", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "NroDetalle");
            SDADetalle.DeleteCommand = CMDDetalle;

            //Insertar fila en Detalle
            CMDDetalle = new MySqlCommand(strInsertDetalle(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?NroCpte", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4);
            CMDDetalle.Parameters["?NroCpte"].Value = intNroCpte;
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?NroDetalle", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4,"NroDetalle");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Producto", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Producto");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?CostoUnt", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 7, "CostoUnt");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?PrecioUnt", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 2, "PrecioUnt");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Cantidad", MySqlDbType.Int32, 4, "Cantidad");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Descuento", MySqlDbType.Int32, 3, "Descuento");
            CMDDetalle.Parameters.Add("?Monto", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 2, "Monto");
            SDADetalle.InsertCommand = CMDDetalle;

            DataTable ChangeRecordsDetalle;
            ChangeRecordsDetalle = dsData.Tables["Detalle"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
            if (ChangeRecordsDetalle != null)
            {
                intRowsAfects = SDADetalle.Update(ChangeRecordsDetalle);
                dsData.Tables["Detalle"].AcceptChanges();
            }

            DataTable DeleteRecordsDetalle;
            DeleteRecordsDetalle = dsData.Tables["Detalle"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
            if (DeleteRecordsDetalle != null)
            {
                intRowsAfects = SDADetalle.Update(DeleteRecordsDetalle);
                dsData.Tables["Detalle"].AcceptChanges();
            }

            DataTable InsertRecordsDetalle;
            InsertRecordsDetalle = dsData.Tables["Detalle"].GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
            if (InsertRecordsDetalle != null)
            {
                intRowsAfects = SDADetalle.Update(InsertRecordsDetalle);
                dsData.Tables["Detalle"].AcceptChanges();
            }
            return intRowsAfects;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "GrabarDetalle", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return intRowsAfects;
        }
    }

    private Boolean CrearDSRegSalida()
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        MySqlCommand CMDComprobante;
        try
        {
            blnTodos = false;
            CMDComprobante = new MySqlCommand(strSelectComprobante(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            SDAComprobante = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            SDAComprobante.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
            SDAComprobante.SelectCommand = CMDComprobante;
            SDAComprobante.FillSchema(dtComprobante, SchemaType.Source);
            SDAComprobante.Fill(dtComprobante);

            SDADetalle = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSelectDetalle(), Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx);
            SDADetalle.FillSchema(dtDetalle, SchemaType.Mapped);
            SDADetalle.Fill(dtDetalle);

            dsData.Tables.Add(dtComprobante);
            dsData.Tables.Add(dtDetalle);

            dtComprobante.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtComprobante.Columns["NroCpte"] };
            dtDetalle.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtDetalle.Columns["NroCpte"], dtDetalle.Columns["NroDetalle"] };

            //Create RelationShip Comprobante - Detalle                
            DataColumn parentColumn = new DataColumn();
            parentColumn = dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].Columns["NroCpte"];
            //parentColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
            //parentColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            //parentColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            parentColumn.Unique = true;               

            DataColumn childColumn = new DataColumn();
            childColumn = dsData.Tables["Detalle"].Columns["NroCpte"];
            //childColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
            //childColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            //childColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            childColumn.Unique = false;

            DataColumn childColumnKey = new DataColumn();
            childColumnKey = dsData.Tables["Detalle"].Columns["NroDetalle"];
            childColumnKey.AutoIncrement = true;
            childColumnKey.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            childColumnKey.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            //childColumn.Unique = true;

            DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("REL_Cmpte_Detalle", parentColumn, childColumn, true);

            dsData.Relations.Add(relation);

            relation.ChildKeyConstraint.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade;
            relation.ChildKeyConstraint.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;
            relation.ChildKeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;

            //ForeignKeyConstraint fk = new ForeignKeyConstraint("ForeignKey", dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].Columns["NroCpte"], dsData.Tables["Detalle"].Columns["NroCpte"]);
            //ForeignKeyConstraint fk = new ForeignKeyConstraint("ForeignKey", parentColumn, childColumn);
            //fk.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade;
            //fk.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade;
            //dtDetalle.Constraints.Add(fk);

            //Create RelationShip Comprobante - controls forms                
            TxtNroCpte.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView, "NroCpte"));
            CmbCliente.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView, "Cliente"));
            TxtDescripcion.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView, "Descripcion"));
            DtFecha.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView, "Fecha"));

            DGVDetalle.DataSource = dsData.Tables["Detalle"].DefaultView;
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColNroCpte.Index].DataPropertyName = "NroCpte";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColNroDetalle.Index].DataPropertyName = "NroDetalle";  
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColProducto.Index].DataPropertyName = "Producto";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColDenominacion.Index].DataPropertyName = "Denominacion";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColUnidad.Index].DataPropertyName = "Unidad";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColCosto.Index].DataPropertyName = "CostoUnt";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColPrVenta.Index].DataPropertyName = "PrecioUnt";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColCantidad.Index].DataPropertyName = "Cantidad";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColDescuento.Index].DataPropertyName = "Descuento";
            DGVDetalle.Columns[ColMonto.Index].DataPropertyName = "Monto";

            //bindingmanager 

            BMBComprobante = this.BindingContext[dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView];
            BMBComprobante.PositionChanged += new EventHandler(Binding_PositionChanged);
            dtComprobante.TableNewRow += new DataTableNewRowEventHandler(dtComprobante_NewRow);
            dtDetalle.TableNewRow += new DataTableNewRowEventHandler(dtDetalle_NewRow);

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "CrearDSRegSalida", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void Binding_PositionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string filter;
        DataRow selectedRow;


        if (this.BindingContext[dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView].Position >= 0)
        {
            selectedRow = dtComprobante.Rows[this.BindingContext[dsData.Tables["Comprobante"].DefaultView].Position];
            strCurrentNroCpte = selectedRow["NroCpte"].ToString();
            filter = "NroCpte=" + strCurrentNroCpte;
            dsData.Tables["Detalle"].DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        }            
    }

    private void dtComprobante_NewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Row["TipoCpte"] = "S";
        e.Row["Fecha"] = DateTime.Now;
        e.Row["Usuario"] = Modulos.ClsGlobal.Usuario;
        e.Row["Descripcion"] = "nuevo";           

    }

    private void dtDetalle_NewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (strCurrentNroCpte.Trim().Length != 0)
        {

            Boolean result = long.TryParse(strCurrentNroCpte, out intNroCpte);                
            e.Row["NroCpte"] = intNroCpte;
            e.Row["TipoCpte"] = "S";
        }
    }

    private Boolean GrabarRegSalida()
    {
        int returnValue = 0;
        try
        {                
            BMBComprobante.EndCurrentEdit();                
            BMBDetalle.EndCurrentEdit();
            if (dsData.HasChanges())
            {
                using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {

                        Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx.Open();
                        if (blnNuevoCpte)
                        {
                            intNroCpte = objF.GetNumeroCpte("S");
                            returnValue = GrabarNroCpte(intNroCpte);
                        }
                        else
                            returnValue = 1;

                    returnValue = GrabarComprobante(intNroCpte);

                    returnValue += GrabarDetalle(intNroCpte);

                    scope.Complete();
                }
                Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx.Close();

            }
            if (returnValue > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "GrabarRegSalida", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Modulos.ClsGlobal.MyNetCnx.Close();
            return false;
        }       
    }


    private void DGVDetalle_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.BindingContext[dsData, "Comprobante"].EndCurrentEdit();
        //BMBComprobante.EndCurrentEdit();
        dsData.AcceptChanges();

        Boolean str = dtComprobante.HasErrors; 

    }
```

When I like to insert a new master row, then i have this error: ForeignKeyConstraint REL_Cmpte_Detalle requires the child key values (0) to exist in the parent table

Please help me.

THANKS, IN ADVANCE.

--

### --Definition of table `tbcomprobante`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbcomprobante`;

CREATE TABLE `tbcomprobante` (

    `idTbComprobante` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

    `NroCpte` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

    `TipoCpte` varchar(1) NOT NULL,

    `Factura` varchar(10) default NULL,

    `Fecha` datetime NOT NULL,

    `Proveedor` varchar(50) default NULL,

    `Cliente` varchar(50) default NULL,

    `Usuario` varchar(5) NOT NULL,

    `Descripcion` varchar(100) default NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY  USING BTREE (`idTbComprobante`)

    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### --Definition of table `tbdetalle`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbdetalle`;

CREATE TABLE `tbdetalle` (

    `idTbDetalle` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

    `NroCpte` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

    `Producto` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

    `Cantidad` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',

    `CostoUnt` decimal(10,7) default '0.0000000',

    `Monto` decimal(10,2) default '0.00',

    `TipoCpte` varchar(1) NOT NULL,

    `PrecioUnt` decimal(10,2) default '0.00',

    `Descuento` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

    `NroDetalle` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY  USING BTREE (`idTbDetalle`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because a Foreign Key restriction has been added to your master-detail table relation, so when you insert the new row into your dataset it is expecting a valid foreign key relationship.

i.e. that the parent table has a row with the corresponding ID. In this case '0'. Here you should check that the key exists.

You can temporarily [turn off constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3bxwk8b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) while filling a table:

```
DataSet1.EnforceConstraints = False
```