# Invalid Constraint Exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have created an test case call GetChangeSetPerProjectTest, below are the code for this test case:

```
public void GetChangeSetPerProjectTest()
    {
        CommonPHIEditorBL_Accessor target = new CommonPHIEditorBL_Accessor();
        target.mCommonPHIEditorDS = new CommonPHIEditorDS();
        AddPHIYieldInfoREBI(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm, 2, 2, 2, 2, 11705, 2, 2);
        AddPHIYieldInfoREBI(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm, 2, 3, 3, 3, 11705, 3, 3); 
        target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm.Rows[1].AcceptChanges();
        target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm.Rows[1].SetModified();
        //For DATA
        AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmData, 2, Convert.ToDateTime("2010-06-20 00:00:00.000"), 2, 2, 2, 2, 11705, 2);
       AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmData, 3, Convert.ToDateTime("2010-06-20 00:00:00.000"), 3, 3, 3, 3, 11705, 2); //error happened at here
        //For Comment Data
        EUPHModelDS.MetricModelCommentDTDataTable newDt = new EUPHModelDS.MetricModelCommentDTDataTable();
        AddEUPHModelDSDataSet(newDt, "MetricModelCommentDT", 2, 2, 2);
        AddEUPHModelDSDataSet(newDt, "MetricModelCommentDT", 4, 2, 2);
        AddEUPHModelDSDataSet(newDt, "MetricModelCommentDT", 3, 3, 3);
        target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.Tables.Add(newDt);

        int projectID = 2; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int expected; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        expected = target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParm.Rows.Count;
        CommonPHIEditorDS actual;
        actual = target.GetChangeSetPerProject(projectID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.PHIYieldParm.Rows.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, actual.PHIYieldParmData.Rows.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Tables["MetricModelCommentDT"].Rows.Count);
        //Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

However, I get an error when I go through the second data for:

> AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmData, 3, Convert.ToDateTime("2010-06-20 00:00:00.000"), 3, 3, 3, 3, 11705, 2);

Inside the AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID:

```
private void AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID(CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmDataDataTable dt, int dataID, DateTime dateKey, int metricID, int inputID, int metricModelInputID, int horizonID, int ItemID, int MetricModelID)
    {
        CommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmDataRow newRow = dt.NewPHIYieldParmDataRow();
        newRow.DataID = dataID;
        newRow.DateKey = dateKey;
        newRow.InputID = inputID;
        newRow.MetricModelInputID = metricModelInputID;
        newRow.ItemID = ItemID;
        newRow.HrzDisplay = "Current Quater";
        newRow.HorizonID = horizonID;
        newRow.Value = 20.7;
        newRow.MetricID = metricID;
        newRow.MetricModelID = 2;
        dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
```

I can successfully go through the first data, but got the error at second data saying that:

> ForeignKeyConstraint FK_PHIYieldParm_PHIYieldParmData requires the child key values (3, 3, 3, 2, 11705) to exist in the parent table.

Comment: And do those values exist in the parent table?

Comment: @paqogomez, my parent table is "AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmData, 3, Convert.ToDateTime("2010-06-20 00:00:00.000"), 3, 3, 3, 3, 11705, 2);", but I have tried to replace with AddPHIYieldDataInfoWithItemID(target.mCommonPHIEditorDS.PHIYieldParmData, 3, Convert.ToDateTime("2010-06-20 00:00:00.000"), 3, 3, 3, 2, 11705, 2);, still get the same error

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17274223/2589202) shows how to disable constraints while setting up your database.  Make sure those values actually exist in the table... (table, not function)